# Unhandled exception Access violation error

Tags: visual-c++

I've been facing this " Access Violation Error" thing throughout these lines. I still couldn't find what's its root cause. I would be considerably grateful if anybody helped me through this.Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
int data;
Node *Next;
};

struct list
{
int count;
Node*Head;
};

void IntializeList(list &L)
{
    L.count=0;
    L.Head=NULL;
}

void AddElement(list &L,int DataIn)
{
    Node*Temp= new Node;
    Node*last=L.Head;
    while(last->Next!=NULL)
    {
        last=last->Next;
    }
    last->Next=Temp;
    Temp->data=DataIn;
    Temp->Next=NULL;
}

void count(Node*L)
{
    int c=0;
    while (L->Next!=NULL)
    {
        L=L->Next;
        c++;
    }

}

void DeleteList(Node*L)
{
    while(L->Next!=NULL)
    {
    Node*temp=L;
    L=L->Next;
    delete temp;
    }
}

void SplitList(list &L)
{
    Node*Mid=L.Head;
    Node*Final=L.Head;
    Node*L2=L.Head;
    /*Final=L->Head->Next->Next;
    Mid=L->Head->Next; */
    while(Final!=NULL)
    {
        Final=Final->Next->Next;
        Mid=Mid->Next;

    }

    Node*L3=Mid->Next;
    Mid->Next=NULL;
    cout<<"L2= ";
    while(L2!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<L2->data;
        L2=L2->Next;
    }

    cout<<"L3= ";
    while(L3!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<L3->data;
        L3=L3->Next;
    }
}

void main()
{
    list L1;
    IntializeList(L1);
    AddElement(L1,2);
    AddElement(L1,3);
    AddElement(L1,4);
    AddElement(L1,5);
    AddElement(L1,9);
    Node*Temp=L1.Head;
    //printing function
    while(Temp->Next!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<Temp->data;
        Temp=Temp->Next;
    }
    SplitList(L1);
}
```

Comment: You would need to provide some backtrace

Answer (score 0):

First, it's better to clarify your question when posting it to SO. 
Since you're running Visual C++, you can try running the program in debugging mode. It will probably show you where the error occurs (or is detected).

Because `head` is initialized to `NULL` when the list was first created, when you call `AddItem`, it would fail on an empty list because `last->Next` is undefined (`last` still being `NULL`). You would need to check whether `last` itself is `NULL` (instead of only checking the next item). You probably need to do the same for the other functions too (such as `deleteList`).